# Image.asset causes app size increased

Tags: ios, xcode5, asset-catalog, uilaunchimagefile, launchimage

I'm using a launch image for iPad Landscape named "Default-Landscape" which is 5.4 MB in size. My app is an universal app and supported from iOS 5, so I have to assign Launch for "iPad Landscape iOS7" and "iPad Landscape iOS5 and iOS6".

[image]

When doing like this, image asset automatically creates separate images for both iOS7 and iOS5,6 named "Default-Landscape" and "Default-Landscape-1". So additional 5.4 MB was added unnecessarily. I know that we can assign Launch images without assets catalog. But I still like to know whether we can assign same image for multiple targets using image asset in Xcode.

Any suggestions please...

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using such heavy image in `launchImage`?

Comment: Actually, the image has more details. I tried to reduce the size but it affect the image quality.

Comment: Are you using a .png or a jpeg? For detailed images, Apple recommends switching to jpegs.

Comment: I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769130/repeated-images-in-asset-catalog-and-to-load-jpg-instead. And I tried loading jpg. It doesn't load. I'm falling back to the traditional method of using naming convention instead for the moment. Please help if any one has an idea how to overcome this unnecessary file size increase.