# Repeated images in asset catalog and to load jpg instead

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog, launchimage

I've created a LaunchImage asset catalog and filled all the empty placeholders for iphone/pad ios6/7.

I've put in 8 images and some are the same files. But asset catalog created a new file to hold these images.

1. Is it possible to reference them to the same images to save file size? My total ImageAsset.xcassets is 22MB which is way too huge.
2. I've tried to edit the Content.json file so that they reference jpg files instead. But no images show up when I test run on my device?

Comment: have you work the repeated images in asset catalog out?